# How to send form data to the URL using php

Tags: php, html

I want to send html from field data like this URL 
http://example/application/intro.php?name=poular&custom_LasName=pappy&email=adasdad12%40gmail.com&webform_id=339693

And want to view that URL value another page like

http:example/application/overview.php

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

The code you sent me in that comment,  (BTW, just update your question,  comments are not good for posting code),  your using a form.  In you're original question you asked about using a query string and getting the data that was passed through the URL.   So which one is it?

To get the code working that you sent me in the comment,  you either need to change ...

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
```

TO ...

```
<form method="get" action="index.php">
```

OR ...

change your $_GET's to $_POST

You should filter this stuff but basically each of those variables will be stored in $_GET superglobal.   You can access them with $_GET['name']  (would equal poular in your example).

You can also do something like ....

```
foreach ($_GET as $k = $v) {

    ${$k} = $v;

}
```

This would produce $name, $custom_LasName, $email, $webform_id

Also extract does the same thing...

```
extract($_GET);
```

You are going to want to sanitize the input though,   all that data can be provided by a user and can be malicious.

Here is how you would sanitize the email..

```
if (!filter_input(INPUT_GET, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo("Email is not valid");
} else {
    echo("Email is valid");
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: fname in C:\xampp\htdocs\form\index.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: lname in C:\xampp\htdocs\form\index.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\form\index.php on line 5

Comment: Here is the code <?php
$name = $_GET['fname'];
$custom_LasName = $_GET['lname'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="text" name="lname">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Great Job! Your tips works Good for this basic from. But i have a Aweber subscription from , if i changed this value "POST" to "GET"  the form did not work at all. This Aweber subscription from used Perl script to handle that form. If i changed any code of that from that from will not work.

Comment: Actually, I want to do like that one http://ksomanagement.com/application/info.php then pass the variable to this url http://ksomanagement.com/application/intro.php then put the url value again to http://ksomanagement.com/application/survey.php   . But my Aweber subscription from use name="name" for each input field. <input id="awf_field-71044792-first" type="text" class="text form-control" name="name (awf_first)" value="">    <input id="awf_field-71044792-last" class="text form-control" type="text form-control" name="name (awf_last)" value="" >

Comment: Great!  If my answer worked for you can you click the checkmark to the left of my answer (under the number)?    Also, can you post this code you just sent to a new question and post a link to the question in the comments here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply GET the values like that:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
$name = $_GET['name'];
}
if(isset($_GET['custom_LastName'])){
$lastname = $_GET['custom_LastName'];
}
if(isset($_GET['email'])){
$email = urldecode($_GET['email']);
}
if(isset($_GET['webform_id'])){
$email = $_GET['webform_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the $_SERVER variable.

With the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] you could pass the data as a hidden form field, or append it to the action attribute.